# Expectation over Gaussian random variable with mean zero and finite variance

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, expectation

Can someone explain me how is the expectation of a random variable (say $X$) calculated over Gaussian random variable with mean zero and a finite variance $\varepsilon\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^{2})$ ?. And what does it intuitively mean to calculate expectation of a random variable over a different random variable $E_\varepsilon(X)$, which in this case is $\varepsilon\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$ ?

Comment: What is $X$? Presumably some expression involving $\epsilon$

Comment: Suppose $X$ and $\epsilon$ are independent but we do know the distribution of X and lets assume it is a gaussian too ?

Comment: If they are independent, then knowing things about $\epsilon$ tells you noting about $X$, and so the expectation of $X$ is what it was before $\epsilon$ was mentioned.  This may not be what was intended

Comment: You question is unclear. Are you asking about the conditional expectation $E(X|\epsilon)$ or integrating with respect to the measure associated to a normal variable?

Comment: @Henry I guess that would be the case with conditional expectation but I am talking about integrating with respect to the measure associated to a normal variable.

Comment: @LoveTooNap29 I guess the above comment answers your query. Btw I tried solving the problem from the very basic starting with the definition of expectation itself and it seems I might have arrived at the answer. My calculations show that if a random variable having a gaussian distribution is integrated over another gaussian distribution the resulting expected value is the sum of the expected value of both the gaussians. Can you please cross-check this with your calculations ?